# Javascript: creating an object instead the return statement? How does this work?

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

I am quite confused by the following code. Why is "set:" instead the return statement? How does one call upon the set function? Thanks

```
BrainBrowser.createTreeStore = function() {

var tree = {};

return {
  set: function() {
    var value = arguments[arguments.length - 1]; 
  },
```

Comment: If that's the whole thing there is no point ever calling it. All it does is assign to a local variable (called `value`) that isn't used. I'm guessing in your code it does other stuff too. Assuming you have done something like `var treeStore = BrainBrowser.createTreeStore();`, You would call it like `treeStore.set( 3, 'little', 'arguments' )` depending on what it actually does with the arguments.

Comment: What is confusing? The return statement is there, it returns an object with a property that happens to be a function so you could later do sth like BrainBrowser.createTreeStore().set()

Comment: @Paulrpo : in this case, does the set : have to be inside the return statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of setter/getter define for `createTreeStore`, use it if you want more behavior when user set a value (or read value) of this object.

For example:

```
Object.defineProperty(document.body, "description", {
    get : function () {
       console.log("You are reading my value!!!");
       return this.desc;
    },
    set : function (val) {
       console.log("Thanks for new value!");
       this.desc = val;
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
document.body.description = "Content container";
```

Open `console` you will see the log:

```
Thanks for new value!
```

Read more here: http://robertnyman.com/2009/05/28/getters-and-setters-with-javascript-code-samples-and-demos/